# Clicking on native device gallery always launches my app

Tags: android, android-intent

My app basically supports sharing of images.
So once I launch the device native gallery, I see my app in the Share option list. I select an image in the device native gallery, hit share, select my app from the list of sharing apps and I am able to share the image into my app. All is good. 
Now if i launch the native gallery again by clicking on the gallery icon, it opens up my app all the time instead of the device native gallery. How do I make the native gallery to be opened up instead of my app?

Please advice.

Comment: Are you properly closing your app after sharing is done? close the gallery and see if your app is shown in task-manager or not, If it visible there then you are not properly exiting your app.

Comment: Naveed - Thanks for your response.Once I share, my app opens up and I see the shared photo in my app. I now minimize my app and go back to the native gallery and once I launch the native gallery, my app opens up instead of the native gallery.

Comment: is it a requirement that you need to minimize the app not dispose of or exit the app.